# Java compare string with hash and without hash

Tags: java, string, hash, compare

I have a String that contains hash (it was automatically generated by third party program) and I have another String that do not contain hash and I need to compare to the first String.

Method `.equals()` give false.
How else I can compare them?

Comment: Never use `==` for strings (btw `==` is not a "method").

Comment: post your input values. equals must work if both are same. Don't expect that a hash of string will be equal to the string.

Comment: What do you want to compare? the hashes or the strings? "equals" should work. Dont use ==.

Comment: I have two identical strings - first contains hash and second not. How can I compare them?

Comment: I want to compare if string values are identical. As I mentioned before - fisrt string contains hash, second - not. Therefore equals() method give false. How else can I do it?

Comment: Thats a contradiction - if first has a hash and the second has not, they are not the same. Please post an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Methods `==` and `.equals()` give `false`, then both the `String` references are not pointing to neither the same object and nor meaningfully equivalent objects in heap. Adding to that, `==` should not be used to compare `String` literals

Answer (score 0):

String values are compared using `equals(String anotherString)`. If that method returns false, the string values are simply not equal.

Check your strings for uppercase vs. lowercase, leading and trailing spaces and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, there are two String to compare, one is the original String (s1) and the second String which contains the original String + its hash (s2) inserted by a 3rd party program. If so, the built-in equals() method will not return true. I would be creating my own implementation of equals() method to check this.

These two methods should do the trick, but I prefer the second one.

```
private static boolean equals(String s1, String s2) {
    String s1Hash = String.valueOf(s1.hashCode());
    return (s2.contains(s1) && s2.contains(s1Hash));
}

private static boolean equals2(String s1, String s2) {
    String s1Hash = String.valueOf(s1.hashCode());
    String s2NoHash = s2.replace(s1Hash,"");
    return (s1.equals(s2NoHash));
}
```

Hope this answers what you are looking for. Otherwise, a concrete example to describe the problem will be good.